# Testing Proc Macro Crates panics - procedural macro API is used outside of a procedural macro

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I would like to test some functionality of the `syn` crate outside of a proc macro, but am getting a panic whenever I create a `proc_macro::TokenStream`.

```rs
use quote::quote;
use syn::parse::Parser;
use syn::punctuated::Punctuated;

fn main(){

  let foo: proc_macro::TokenStream = quote!(Bar, Bazz).into();
  let parsed = Punctuated::<syn::Ident, syn::Token![,]>::parse_terminated.parse(foo);

}

// procedural macro API is used outside of a procedural macro
```

Answer (score 0):

`syn` and other crates have `parse2` and equivelant functions that allow us to use a `proc_macro2::TokenStream` instead:

```rust
let foo = quote!(Bar, Bazz);
let parsed = Punctuated::<syn::Ident, syn::Token![,]>::parse_terminated.parse2(foo);
```